# SVG Bug on Firefox? Scale

Tags: firefox, svg

As you can see below, when I scale SVGs in Firefox 31, on some scales, they have errors on the edges. As Internet Explorer and Chrome do scale correctly, is this a bug, or shouldn't I use img tags to include svg-images?
Here's how I included the images:

```
<img src="img/svg/kalender_icon.svg" alt="Kalender Icon" />
```

[image: SVG Bug]
[image: SVG No Bug]

Comment: Tip: Consult [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) to determine global browser support for $new_technology_X.

Comment: caniuse tells me that there should be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in Firefox 34 (on 2014-11-25) by [bug 1043560](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043560) In the meantime try to ensure that image dimensions are integers.